# Is there an in-universe reason for this Infinity Gauntlet difference in Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In Endgame, after

> going across time and collecting all the Infinity Stones,

the Avengers (Tony, Banner and Rocket) together work on

> creating a new Gauntlet to wield the stones. And in doing so, they create a right-handed Gauntlet as opposed to Thanos’ left-handed one.
>
>  [image]

Is there a reason why they did this?

Comment: ~90% of the population is right-handed?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist then  does that mean Thanos was *left-handed*?

Comment: I don't believe there has been an in universe or out of universe explanation, but lots of films/TV shows portray baddies as being left handed, or have them appearing more often on the left hand side of the screen.

Comment: Side-note: The word sinister is derived from the Latin sinistra, which means left or left-handed.

Comment: Does that mean Iron Man is *right-handed*?

Comment: Maybe to show that they are _opposite_ to Thanos? Or it's just a coincidence? How does it matter?

Comment: @INTERESTING idk but, since when is anything in the MCU a coincidence? i mean there's always some hidden meaning behind everything have do right?

Comment: @Shreedhar There doesn't have to be, but good point.

Comment: So they can wear both at once and be twice as infinitely powerful, obviously.

Comment: For the record, I can't snap my fingers with my left hand.

Comment: I can snap my fingers with both.

Comment: @RichS Wouldn't a left-handed engineer would operate his tools with his left hand while building the gauntlet on his right hand?

Comment: This title is overly spoiler proofed to the point it means nothing.

Answer (score 5):

I feel like it's worth mentioning the different purposes of the gauntlets here.

Thanos' gauntlet is intended as an accessory, he's wearing it while still being martial and fighting with his dominant hand:
[image: Ripping Tony's helmet off]
[image: Punching]
[image: Punching again]

The gauntlet is on the off-hand and used for either blocking like a shield:
[image: Shielding]
Or power attacks specifically designed for it:
[image: Zap]

On the counterpoint, the Avenger's gauntlet was never intended to be a martial device. It was built to undo the snap and that's it, so it would be reasonable to assume that putting it on the dominant hand would give the user any advantage possible.